# MongoDB: Finding all documents for which a certain field in an array is always true

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

This is the `bios` collection that I found on the official [MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bios-example-collection/):

```json
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : {
            "first" : "John",
            "last" : "Backus"
        },
        "awards" : [
            {
                "award" : "W.W. McDowell Award",
                "year" : 1967,
                "by" : "IEEE Computer Society",
                "monetaryRewards": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : {
            "first" : "John",
            "last" : "McCarthy"
        },
        "awards" : [
            {
                "award" : "Turing Award",
                "year" : 1971,
                "by" : "ACM",
                "monetaryRewards": true
            },
            {
                "award" : "Kyoto Prize",
                "year" : 1988,
                "by" : "Inamori Foundation",
                "monetaryRewards": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "name" : {
            "first" : "Grace",
            "last" : "Hopper"
        },
        "awards" : [
            {
                "award" : "Computer Sciences Man of the Year",
                "year" : 1969,
                "by" : "Data Processing Management Association",
                "monetaryRewards": true
            },
            {
                "award" : "Distinguished Fellow",
                "year" : 1973,
                "by" : " British Computer Society",
                "monetaryRewards": true
            },
            {
                "award" : "W. W. McDowell Award",
                "year" : 1976,
                "by" : "IEEE Computer Society",
                "monetaryRewards": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am trying to write a query that will allow me to retrieve all documents for which all `monetaryRewards` are true. Thus, considering the previous documents:

```
_id = 1 -> there is only one monetaryRewards and it is false. The query should not select it;
_id = 2 -> There are three awards and the monetaryRewards fields are always true. The query should select it;
_id = 3 -> There are three awards where monetaryRewards is twice true and once false. The query should not select it;
```

I wrote the following query:

```js
    db.bios.find( { awards: {$not: {$elemMatch:{"monetaryRewards":false}}}} )
```

The query works correctly. Later I realised that my `bios` collection might also not contain the `monetaryRewards` field, for example there could be another document:

```json
    {
           "_id" : 4,
           "name" : {
               "first" : "Kristen",
               "last" : "Nygaard"
           },
           "awards" : [
               {
                   "award" : "Rosing Prize",
                   "year" : 1999,
                   "by" : "Norwegian Data Association",
                   "monetaryRewards":true
               },
               {
                   "award" : "Turing Award",
                   "year" : 2001,
                   "by" : "ACM"
               }
       }
```

In this situation my query fails because it takes the lack of `monetaryRewards` as true while in my case it should be false.

How can I fix my query?

Here you can find the [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g5PF4ncodaA) where you can see that the document with _id=4 is incorrectly selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `$map` the `awards.monetaryRewards` to an auxiliary array of booleans. Use `$ifNull` to cater the missing field case. Then use `$allElementsTrue` to perform the filtering.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "filterArr": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$awards",
          "as": "a",
          "in": {
            $ifNull: [
              "$$a.monetaryRewards",
              false
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$allElementsTrue": "$filterArr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      filterArr: false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CudD5GaUSGR) for your reference.

Comment: The aggregation does not work correctly. 
It selects the document with _id = 4 when it should not be found.

Comment: Can be done similarly without the $map: 
````
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      filterArr: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$awards",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item.monetaryRewards", true]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [{$size: "$awards"},{$size: "$filterArr"}]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {filterArr: false}
  }
])
````

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana sorry my bad. updated the solution for $map to use `$awards` instead of the original `$awards.monetaryRewards`. Would you please help to confirm if it works now?

Comment: @nimrodserok Thanks for your supplement. That's a good solution.